# Unit testing a directive that uses ComponentFactory and Injector

Tags: angular, unit-testing, angular2-directives

Using Angular 4.2, I have written a directive that builds a component on the fly and inserts it into the DOM using Angular's ComponentFactory and Injector. Here's an example of the code:

https://plnkr.co/edit/wO9EWWJZxEL221ktsZGE?p=preview

I want to write a spec for this directive. Normally I would build a test component and attach it to the test bed. However, the directive injects its component into the document DOM which does not exist in a test bed. How do I test for the directive's behavior?

Example spec (pseudo-code):

```
@Component({
    template: '<h3 appExample>Example</h3>'
})
class TestComponent {}

describe('ExampleDirective', () => {
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<TestComponent>;

    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [ BrowserModule ],
            declarations: [
                TestComponent,
                ExampleDirective,
                ExampleDirectiveComponent
            ]
        });

        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestComponent);
        fixture.detectChanges();
    });

    it('should fire directive', fakeAsync(() => {
        const template = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('h3'));
        template.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('click'));
        fixture.detectChanges();
        tick();
        console.log('fixture', fixture.componentInstance);
    }));
});
```

The console.log shows that nothing has been attached to the fixture even though the directive was fired.

Comment: here _console.log('fixture', fixture.componentInstance);_ - will hold the reference to the `TestComponent ` instance, what did you expect it to be?

Comment: The console.log is just to demonstrate that the ExampleDirectiveComponent is not being inserted into the fixture. How else can we test to see that the directive is injecting something into the DOM?

Comment: why do you insert the component into the view container `this._exampleRef = this._viewContainerRef.createComponent(this._factory, 0, this._injector, []);` and then move it in the DOM `this._document.body.appendChild(this._exampleRef.location.nativeElement);`?  `

Comment: Because the container does not exist beforehand. In Angular's dynamic loader example (https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader) the container always exists and just needs to be filled with subcomponents. In my case the container is built and destroyed on the fly based on mouse events.

Comment: the view container is created during compilation, it can't be created or destroyed dynamically. what do you mean by `container`?

Comment: I may be misunderstanding how to inject dynamically created components into the DOM, or at least doing it inelegantly. How else would you approach it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152218/discussion-between-ebakunin-and-maximus).